# issue calling uniswap quoter contract functions

Tags: javascript

I'm having a issue call a function of uniswap quoter contract. I keep getting this error:
TypeError: check is not a function
at Object.refinement (/Users/fallenangel226/Documents/price-bot/node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:200:28)
at executeRefinement (/Users/fallenangel226/Documents/price-bot/node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:3004:39)
at ZodEffects._parse (/Users/fallenangel226/Documents/price-bot/node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:3024:17)
at /Users/fallenangel226/Documents/price-bot/node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:2398:27
at Array.map ()
at ZodTuple._parse (/Users/fallenangel226/Documents/price-bot/node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:2394:14)
at ZodTuple._parseSync (/Users/fallenangel226/Documents/price-bot/node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:129:29)
at ZodTuple.safeParse (/Users/fallenangel226/Documents/price-bot/node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:159:29)
at Validator.validate (/Users/fallenangel226/Documents/price-bot/node_modules/web3-validator/lib/commonjs/validator.js:66:28)
at Web3Validator.validate (/Users/fallenangel226/Documents/price-bot/node_modules/web3-validator/lib/commonjs/web3_validator.js:35:32)
I've checked my inputs and I've verified that the function I'm trying to call is a function. This worked last night so now I'm a little confused.

```
const UNISWAP_QUOTER_ADDRESS = '0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6'
const uniswapABI = [{"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "_factory", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "_WETH9", "type": "address"}], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "WETH9", "outputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "factory", "outputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "bytes", "name": "path", "type": "bytes"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "quoteExactInput", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOut", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "tokenIn", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "tokenOut", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "uint24", "name": "fee", "type": "uint24"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint160", "name": "sqrtPriceLimitX96", "type": "uint160"}], "name": "quoteExactInputSingle", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOut", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "bytes", "name": "path", "type": "bytes"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOut", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "quoteExactOutput", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "tokenIn", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "tokenOut", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "uint24", "name": "fee", "type": "uint24"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOut", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint160", "name": "sqrtPriceLimitX96", "type": "uint160"}], "name": "quoteExactOutputSingle", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "int256", "name": "amount0Delta", "type": "int256"}, {"internalType": "int256", "name": "amount1Delta", "type": "int256"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "path", "type": "bytes"}], "name": "uniswapV3SwapCallback", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}]
const uniswapQuoterContract = new web3.eth.Contract(uniswapABI, UNISWAP_QUOTER_ADDRESS)

const uniswapResult = await uniswapQuoterContract.methods.quoteExactInputSingle([inputTokenAddress, outputTokenAddress, 3000, inputAmount, 0]).call()
```